# Rails + Apache + Passenger + EC2 Linux AMI "Incomplete Response From Application"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, apache, amazon-ec2

I am getting served "Incomplete Response From Application" on a fresh install of Apache 2 + Rails 4 + Phusion Passenger. I followed the instructions found [here](http://blog.sunild.com/2013/07/installing-rails-40-on-amazon-web.html), but as I am no sysadmin, I really was operating mostly blind. At first, when I checked the logs, I was missing a javascript runtime environment. I am guessing passenger is written in JS or something like that, not sure why I would need it, so I added `gem 'execjs'` to the gemfile and installed nodejs on my linux AMI using `sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel` The only other deviations I took from that guide were that I changed the default `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` in my `httpd.conf` as I have no server name yet for a vhost. Thanks for your time!

Someone on SO referenced this as a solution:

```
Enter your app root
run: rake secret
copy the output
go to /yourapp/config/secrets.yml
set the production secret_key_base
```

This causes the entire app to not respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had the security group not accepting any connections except from my machine on the RDS database for production.